# My navigation menu isn't working. What happened? Please help!

Tags: menus, navigation

It stopped working after I made some edits to my posts using the Yellow Pencil plugin. Does anyone have any idea how to fix this? Blog website link here: https://aspiringtonothingness.com

Answer (score 1):

The wrapper element has a higher priority than your menu (position relative) and lies over your menu element.

Two solutions:

1) Remove the negative "top" value from the .wrapper element in css

-> *top: -66px;*

and add less padding-top instead.

2) Add a z-index value to your navigation element, for example z-index: 10

[image: wrapper demo]